# function importxml google spreadsheet

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I have to learn xpath and I try to using importxml function in google spreadsheet but it doesn't work.

Using firefox I found 2 addons that show me the xpath code, ("firebug" and "xpath checker").
with firebug I have this xpath:

```
 /html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/form/h1
```

and with xpath checker this code:

```
id('titolo1')/h1
```

I tried to use this code:

```
=importXML("url";"//*[@id='titolo1']/h1")
=importXML("url";"//html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/form/h1")
=importXML("url";"id('titolo1')/h1")
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone see where the problem may lie?

Answer (score 2):

Show Your HTML for H1, in general cases:

```
//*[@id='titolo1']/h1
```

must work.

Else - check syntactic (' vs "). Else - try to see broader where problem is (google spreadsheet sometimes has weird behaviour), for example:

```
//*[@id='titolo1']
//form
...etc.
```